# Storage::get() results in a FileNotFoundException

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to load a external JSON file into my laravel application. Below you will find a snippet of my code.

```
$location = __DIR__.'/config.json';
echo $location;               // Results in correct file location
echo File::exists($location); // Return 1
echo Storage::get($location); // Throws a FileNotFound Exception
```

How can the `File::exists()` method return `true` and the `Storage::get()` throw an exception?

My `config/filesystems.php` file:

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Can you show your `config/filesystems.php` file? ( with `disks` key).

Comment: Added it to the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use the `Storage` class for this? That class is specifically for accessing the storage folder or external file servers. You stored your file right next to your controller/code, so it's probably easier to do it the old-fashioned way.

```
$location = __DIR__.'/config.json';

if (File::exists($location)) {
    $string = file_get_contents($location);
    $json = json_decode($string, true);

    // logic
} else {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: No problem. Take a look at Sergio Reis's answer too, his is more Laravel-y, mine isn't ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try accessing it through the file facade by

```
File::get($location);
```

The error is probably because Storage is trying to access the file from its default path (./project/storage/app) plus what you send it. My best advice, is to add a new disk 
like this

```
// config/filesystems.php

'customDrive' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
   'root' => base_path(), // here put your full path
],
```

and acess it through

```
Storage::disk("customDrive")->get("config.json");
```

**Source** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem